# GORM Gloang Models Hooks Inheritance Issue

Tags: postgresql, go, inheritance, hook, go-gorm

I have a base model that then I go and expand onto all my other models. In my base model I have a BeforeCreate hook which assigns a custom ID for objects. Then I added another model which also has a BeforeCreate Hook. I understand that in inheritance if parent and child has same method, the child method will take priority. Assuming that's the case, is there a way I can solve this issue, other than having to call my ID function every time in children hook?

Here are the code sample:

```
type BaseModel struct {
    // Unique identifier for the object.
    ID string `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key"`
    // Time at which the object was created. Measured in seconds since the Unix epoch.
    CreatedAt int64 `json:"created_at" gorm:"index;not null;"`
    // Time at which the object was updated. Measured in seconds since the Unix epoch.
    UpdatedAt int64 `json:"updated_at" gorm:"index;not null;"`
}

func (b *BaseModel) BeforeCreate(tx *gorm.DB) (err error) {
    b.CreatedAt = time.Now().Unix()
    b.UpdatedAt = time.Now().Unix()
    b.ID = id.New(tx.Statement.Table)
    return
}


type BaseModelSoftDelete struct {
    BaseModel
    // Time at which the object was deleted. Measured in seconds since the Unix epoch.
    DeletedAt gorm.DeletedAt `json:"deleted_at" gorm:"index;"`
}

func (b *BaseModelSoftDelete) BeforeCreate(tx *gorm.DB) (err error) {
    b.CreatedAt = time.Now().Unix()
    b.UpdatedAt = time.Now().Unix()
    b.ID = id.New(tx.Statement.Table)
    return
}

// APIClientUser is the application model.
type APIClientUser struct {
    BaseModelSoftDelete
    // WhitelistIPs is the application's whitelist IPs.
    WhitelistIPs *pq.StringArray `json:"whitelist_ips" gorm:"type:text[];"`
}

func checkIPAddress(ip *string) error {
    if net.ParseIP(*ip) == nil {
        return errors.New("invalid ip address")
    }
    return nil
}

func (b *APIClientUser) BeforeCreate(tx *gorm.DB) (err error) {
    // If I comment this my id is set empty string and next time I try to create, gives duplicate key issue
    b.ID = id.New(tx.Statement.Table)

    if b.WhitelistIPs != nil {
        for _, ip := range *b.WhitelistIPs {
            if err = checkIPAddress(&ip); err != nil {
                return
            }
        }
    }

    return
}
```

Comment: You can directly call the embedded structs function in Go. So you can just do `b.BaseModelSoftDelete.BeforeCreate(tx)` in APIClientUser's BeforeCreate.

Comment: that is the approach I decided to go with, thanks.